# Choosing different libraries for compilation and runtime

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, static-libraries, aar

I have two libraries with same classes defined in each one. However they have some different contents (methods/constants).

For example:

Library 1:

```
package com.test.package;
Class A {
     // only method signatures
     public void methodA() {
     }

     public void methodB() {
     }
}
```

Library 2:

```
package com.test.package;
Class A {  
     public void methodA() {
          // some logic that MUST be executed to provide backward compatibility
     }
}
```

My application uses Library 1 and Library 2 and run in devices which have `com.test.package.ClassA`, but `com.test.package.ClassA.methodB()` will only exist in newer releases in framework. Said that, I need the Library 1 to be used to compile my application and the Library 2 to execute a different implementation of `methodA()`.

I have tried to do this in Android Studio using .jar and .aar libraries format, but none of them worked for me.

Is it possible to set this configuration in an Android Studio project?

I am building both Library 1 and 2, and I cannot add methodB() in Library 2.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple Java application, you can do this by unlinking the `compile` and `runtime` configurations. I set up an example repository [here](https://github.com/jvff/gradle_unlink_runtime_from_compile_configuration_example).

The idea is shown in [this commit](https://github.com/jvff/gradle_unlink_runtime_from_compile_configuration_example/commit/8c046792447942c277dd94e54366e7e8894f0e2d), but can be described as manually resetting the `runtime` configuration so that it doesn't include the contents of the `compile` configuration. After doing so, you can just include your runtime library variation in the `runtime` configuration.

The application's `build.gradle` becomes something like:

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'my.package.MyAppClass'

configurations.runtime.extendsFrom = [] // Reset runtime configuration

dependencies {
    compile 'my.group:my.artifact:2.0'  // Library 1, with the new method
    runtime 'my.group:my.artifact:1.0'  // Library 2, without the method
}
```

For Android, this can be a little more complicated. The problem is that there's no `runtime` configuration for Android (because you don't execute it on your computer, unless you're using Robolectric or something similar).

I think there are a few workarounds you can probably use, but one initial suggestion would be to create a wrapper library that abstracts away the dependency on the other libraries. This wrapper library you can compile with the newest library version (Library 1, with the new method). You could then include the wrapper library in the Android app while setting it as a non-transitive dependency and including the other library version:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'my.group:my.wrapped.artifact:0.1' {
        transitive = false  // Don't include dependencies of the wrapper
                            // i.e., don't include version 2.0 of the lib.
    }
    compile 'my.group:my.artifact:1.0'
}
```

This should work because by setting the dependency as non-transitive Gradle doesn't recursively include the dependencies of the wrapper library, so the version used to compile the wrapper isn't included (in theory) in the APK. You can therefore add the old version without causing a conflict.

An example is set up in the same repository, under the [Android branch](https://github.com/jvff/gradle_unlink_runtime_from_compile_configuration_example/tree/android). Firstly, two Java libraries are created. Then [an Android library is created](https://github.com/jvff/gradle_unlink_runtime_from_compile_configuration_example/commit/388bbb8a2e31ca90a0a44553721b0732483bcf17) to wrap around the compile-time library. An [example activity is created](https://github.com/jvff/gradle_unlink_runtime_from_compile_configuration_example/commit/dd07a7487ddd895d8139e63867f4d05467b89c62) to show how using the wrapper library uses the compile-time library. Then, the [latest commit](https://github.com/jvff/gradle_unlink_runtime_from_compile_configuration_example/commit/068b9e0ec7d410e500e22567e7d8b5017659159b) shows how the app is configured to use the wrapper library (which compiles with the newest library) but forces the old library to be included instead in the runtime.

Hope this helps =)